# override ugly two tone border style on input

Tags: css, input, border

I've done this before with inputs, why on earth does this not work?

http://euroworker.no/user/checkout

```
input.text, select, file, form.other
{
    width: 15em;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 2px;
  border-width:1px;
 border-color:#dddddd;
 border-style:inset;
 border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 outline:none;
}
```

Just want it one colour, #dddddd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
border: 5px solid #dddddd;
```

"Solid" gives you a solid colour, whereas "Inset" gives you an erm... inset border.

Answer (score 1):

```
border-style:solid;
```